# How to acces Class methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, class-method

I have a class method which takes an Array as the parameter

```
+(void)classMethod:(NSArray*)array;
```

A message is being sent to this method from an outside ViewController with the value of the array.

```
[ViewController classMethod:ValueofArray]
```

Now i want to access the value of that array from an instance method in the same ViewController as the  Class method

```
-(void)instanceMethod;
```

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a static class level variable to hold the value.

For example:

```
@implementation SOMyObject

static NSArray *thisArray;


+(NSArray*) thisArray
{
    return thisArray;
}

+(void) myMethod:(NSArray*) array;
{
    thisArray = array;
}

-(void) doWork
{
    //[SOMyObject thisArray]
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Now i want to access the value of that array from an instance method in the same ViewController as the Class method

But the point of a class method is that it is not an instance of the class.  You use a class method when you don't need to see any of the variables or properties of class.  For example a method like `[MyClass countVowels:someString];` could perform its actions without any 'state', so it could be a candidate for a class method.

On the other hand, if you write "`[myClass countVowels];`" it implies something like this:

```
MyClass * myClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithString:@"some string]];
int howMany = [myClass countVowels];
```

This 2nd version would presumably store the string passed to the init method, and later count the vowels in that string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have mixed feelings on this answer. In such, a class method could indeed perform a function (as per the example that you mention), but there's no reason why it can't be used to set (or increment/decrement) a shared static variable.

Comment: Very true, but that should be left to folks who know how to do that and all the ramifications of such code.  I was tempted to mention the common case of singleton; or how the static method could grab the 'sharedInstance' of that class; but didn't want to lead him down that rabbit hole. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class variable, outside the header and implementation of the class.

Here's an example:

```
// MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (void)setClassArray:(NSArray *)array;
+ (NSArray *)classArray;
@end


// MyClass.m

#import "MyClass.h"

static NSArray *_myClassArray;

@implementation MyClass

+ (NSArray *)classArray
{
    return _myClassArray;
}

+ (void)setClassArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    if (_myClassArray != array)
    {
        _myClassArray = array;
    }
}

@end
```

Hence, you would set the value of the class array like this:

```
[MyClass setClassArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Some_Objects"]];
```

Within an instance of the class, you could access it like this:

```
- (void)myInstanceMethod
{
    // setting to another ivar is optional and only shown for clarity

   NSArray *array = _myClassArray;
    // ... do whatever you want to do with it here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true that class methods are usually (and supposed to be) state-less functional entities, what you're looking for is possible. In this case, there is a single array that all instances of `MyViewController` want to use, so other classes setting that info just don't care.

```
MyViewController.m

static NSArray *staticArray;

+ (void)aClassMethod:(NSArray *)array
{
    staticArray = array;
}

- (void)anInstanceMethod
{
    NSLog(@"My staticArray: %@", staticArray);
}
```

All that said, it's a pretty specific and non-standard case. You might rethink your use case, maybe you actually want a delegate pattern, a default singleton like `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`, or something else. Or you actually have a good use case for this. Nice.

In any case, there you have it.